# AngularJS Implementing a localization for templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to implement a localization for views (should include the body, too).
I've done this before by loading a JSON File and than iterate trough the keys.
The keys are class names. Than i simply assign the value of the key to the
element with the class.

**Language File (JSON)**

```
".Header-Title" :   "My Title",
".Header-Text"  :   "Lorem ipsum vehicula interdum."
```

**Code Example**

```
$.load("./Content/Text/main-en.json", function(data) {
   for (key in data) {
     $(key).html(data[key]);
   }
});
```

I liked this because the text is separated from html and script. Like to know can i accomplish this in AngularJS. My thoughts are to extend the route provider by a additional parameter that takes the path
to the JSON Language File. After loading a view a function should be called that's assign the
values like in the code example. Just have started with AngularJS. Any ideas or help ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Localization Service](https://github.com/lavinjj/angularjs-localizationservice) by [Coding SmackDown TV](http://codingsmackdown.tv/blog/2012/12/14/localizing-your-angularjs-app/)

**1) Load the service, and include your i18n file. For instance, take this**

```
// /i18/en/dictionary_en.js
[
    {
        "key":"_More_",
        "value":"More",
        "description":"More button"
    }
]

// In the localize service
$http({ method:"GET", url:url, cache:false }).success(localize.successCallback).error(function () {
    // the request failed set the url to the default resource file
    var url = '/i18n/en/dictionary_en.js';
    localize.language = 'en';
    // request the default resource file
    $http({ method:"GET", url:url, cache:false }).success(localize.successCallback);
});
```

**2) In your views use the i18 filter or through `ng-bind`**

```
<button data-i18n="_More_">
```