# AngularJS Extend the routeprovider parameters and call a function for any route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to extend the `routeProvider` and implement additional parameter (like `templateUrl`). Then every time any route gets triggered I want call a function with the scope on the additional parameter from the `routeProvider`.

```
$routeProvider
.when("/Index",
{
    templateUrl:"./Views/index.html",
    controller:"IndexCtrl",
    myParam: "./Content/Text/file.json"
})
.always(function (myParam) 
{
    do something for any view with myParam parameter...
}
```

The background behind the this question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833813/angularjs-implementing-a-localization-for-templates). I will appreciate any help.

Comment: You might want to use the routeProvider's `resolve` function.

Comment: Subscribe on the `$routeChangeStart` or `$routeChangeSuccess` event, you'll be able to get the current route from the arguments and access `route.<param>` or `route.scope`.